# getting a parse error and cannot find eslint file

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, eslint

I've realized that you can't send messages directly from the client with the FCM v1 API so now I'm using node.js and I wan't to deploy this cloud function, but I am getting a parse error like so:

[image: error]

This is my function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { event } = require("firebase-functions/lib/providers/analytics");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotificationsToTopic = 
functions.firestore.document("school_users/{uid}/events/{docID}").onWrite(async (event) => {
let docID = event.after.id;
let schoolID = event.after.get("school_id")
let title = "New Event!!"
let notificationBody = "A new event has been added to the dashboard!!"
var message = {
  notification: {
      title: title,
      body: notificationBody,
  },
  topic: schoolID,

};

let response = await admin.messaging().sendToTopic(message);
console.log(response);
});
```

I did some research and found people were getting similar errors with their projects, and answers were saying to update the version of eslint so it picks up on the shorthand syntax, I can't figure out where to find the eslint file to update the version. Does anybody know where I can find this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was show my hidden files in my `functions` directory. Once I seen the `.eslintrc.js` file, I simply removed a part of a value from the "eslint" key, and the function deployed perfectly fine.